# Cannot insertAdjacentElement of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I have a button element I want to create a ul with a click event. The newly created list should also get a li element. This should also be done with a click element.

But the querySelector is always null when I try to select the ul to append the li.

```js
document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.setAttribute("id", "liste");
  document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", list);

  let listelement = document.createElement("li");
  listelement.textContent = "test"
  document.querySelector("liste").insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", listelement);
});
```

```html
<h2 id="headline">List</h2>
<form id="input-form">
  <input type="submit" value="Hinzufügen" id="add">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector("liste")` is trying to access a tag called liste. You mean `document.querySelector("#liste")` or better: `document.getElementById("liste")`

You can only add such element with the same ID once, since IDs need to be unique.

I suggest you have the UL as a static element on the page and do not create it on click

And use the submit event to add to the list

```js
"use strict"

document.getElementById("input-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let listelement = document.createElement("li");
  listelement.textContent = document.getElementById("todo").value;
  document.getElementById("liste").insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", listelement);
});
```

```html
<h2 id="headline">List</h2>
<form id="input-form">
  <input type="text" id="todo" />
  <input type="submit" value="Hinzufügen">
</form>
<ul id="liste"></ul>
```

If you really want a UL with an LI on each click, you can do

```js
"use strict"

document.getElementById("input-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const idx = container.querySelectorAll("ul").length;
  const list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.setAttribute("id", "liste" + idx);
  container.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", list);
  let listelement = document.createElement("li");
  listelement.textContent = document.getElementById("todo").value || "test"; // if nothing entered
  list.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", listelement);
});
```

```html
<h2 id="headline">List</h2>
<form id="input-form">
  <input type="text" id="todo" />
  <input type="submit" value="Hinzufügen">
</form>
<div id="container"></div>
```

If you later need to do something on click of the LI, then you can delegate from the container:

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li");
  if (tgt) console.log(tgt.innerText);
})
```

Comment: To do list is not even maintained in question, and i think rather then attaching listener to each element the idea of delegation would be better https://javascript.info/event-delegation, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I disagree. I am the first one to suggest delegation. In this case, OP obviously has ONE form and ONE button that adds an LI to a UL. There is no need for delegation here

Comment: @RoguSmith I added a version that adds a UL every time

Comment: No i was more like thinking that OP also needs the event listener in the `li` element, the idea of the `UL` being  a static element is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just miss to add **#** before the **liste** id of last **querySelector**. Try the below updated code.

```
document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let list = document.createElement("ul");
    list.setAttribute("id","liste");
    document.querySelector("body").insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",list);

    let listelement = document.createElement("li");
    listelement.textContent = "test"
    document.querySelector("#liste").insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin",listelement);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i think its null because querySelector target is wrong try with `querySelector("#liste")`. (notice the "#")